Is the total angular momentum $J$ a good quantum number for the Breit intereaction?
I am reformulating this question because the previous one was closed to the to the claim that is a homework question.
According to Wikipedia the Breit operator is given by
$$
\hat{B}_{i j}=-\frac{1}{2 r_{i j}}\left[\vec{\alpha}(i) \cdot \vec{\alpha}(j)+\frac{\left(\vec{\alpha}(i) \cdot \mathbf{r}_{i j}\right)\left(\vec{\alpha}(j) \cdot \mathbf{r}_{i j}\right)}{r_{i j}^2}\right]
$$
Is the total angular momentum $J=L+S$ a good a quantum number in  2 electron system?

I don't know why this was closed; this is a legitimate conceptual question about whether total angular momentum is a good quantum number in the presence of the Breit interaction (btw yes, $B_{12}$ does commute with $\vec{j}_1+\vec{j}_2$).

@dennismoore94 I’m not involved in the VtClose but lots of things undefined in the above.  Agreed that if $B_{ij}$ is a scalar it will commute with angular momenta but this is impossible to answer with the information we have now.

in fact see this post by same OP.

Let us consider the two-electron case (generalization being straightforward) and take the general interaction
$$
 W(\boldsymbol{r}_1,\boldsymbol{r}_2)=
 v(r_{12})I\otimes I+
 w(r_{12})\boldsymbol{\alpha}_1\boldsymbol{\alpha}_2+
 \frac{\bar{w}(r_{12})}{r_{12}^2}(\boldsymbol{\alpha}_1\cdot\boldsymbol{r}_{12})(\boldsymbol{\alpha}_2\cdot\boldsymbol{r}_{12}) \ ,
$$
where $\boldsymbol{r}_{12}=\boldsymbol{r}_{1}-\boldsymbol{r}_{2}$, ${r}_{12}=|\boldsymbol{r}_{1}-\boldsymbol{r}_{2}|$, $v$, $w$ and $\bar{w}$ are scalar functions, and
$$
\alpha_{1a}=
\begin{bmatrix}
\emptyset & \sigma_a \\
\sigma_a & \emptyset 
\end{bmatrix}
\otimes I \ \ , \ \ 
\alpha_{2a}=
I\otimes
\begin{bmatrix}
\emptyset & \sigma_a \\
\sigma_a & \emptyset 
\end{bmatrix} \ .
$$
For
$$
v(r_{12})=\frac{\alpha}{r_{12}} \ \ , \ \ w(r_{12})=\bar{w}(r_{12})=-\frac{\alpha}{2r_{12}} \ ,
$$
we would get the Coulomb-Breit interaction (the $\alpha$ fine structure constant here is not to be confused with the $\boldsymbol{\alpha}$ Dirac matrices).
We want to show $[\boldsymbol{J},W]=\boldsymbol{0}$ for
$$
\boldsymbol{J}=\boldsymbol{L}+\boldsymbol{S}=\boldsymbol{L}_1+\boldsymbol{L}_2+\boldsymbol{S}_1+\boldsymbol{S}_2 \ ,
$$
where $S_{ia}=\Sigma_{ia}/2$, with
$$
\Sigma_{1a}=
\begin{bmatrix}
\sigma_a & \emptyset \\
\emptyset & \sigma_a
\end{bmatrix}
\otimes I \ \ , \ \ 
\Sigma_{2a}=
I\otimes
\begin{bmatrix}
\sigma_a & \emptyset \\
\emptyset & \sigma_a
\end{bmatrix} \ .
$$
First, note that $\boldsymbol{L}=\boldsymbol{L}_1+\boldsymbol{L}_2$ commutes with any $f(r_{12})$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\
[L_a,f(r_{12})]
&=-i\epsilon_{abc}\left(x_{1b}\partial_{1c}f(r_{12})+x_{2b}\partial_{2c}f(r_{12})\right) \\
&=-i\epsilon_{abc}\left(x_{1b}-x_{2b}\right)\partial_{1c}f(r_{12}) \\
&=-if'(r_{12})\epsilon_{abc}\left(x_{1b}-x_{2b}\right)\partial_{1c}r_{12} \\
&=-i\frac{f'(r_{12})}{r_{12}}\epsilon_{abc}\left(x_{1b}-x_{2b}\right)\left(x_{1c}-x_{2c}\right) \\
&=0 \ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
which is zero because a permutationally symmetric quantity is contracted to $\epsilon_{abc}$ (we could have argued this based on rotational symmetry, too).
This of course means $[J_a,f(r_{12})]=0$ for $\boldsymbol{J}=\boldsymbol{L}+\boldsymbol{S}$ as well. The first term of $W$ then trivially commutes with $\boldsymbol{J}$. In the second term, we need the simple commutator identity
$$
[S_a,\alpha_{ib}]=i\epsilon_{abc}\alpha_{ic} \ ,
$$
which leads to
$$
\begin{aligned}
\
[J_a,w(r_{12})\alpha_{1b}\alpha_{2b}]
&=
w(r_{12})[J_a,\alpha_{1b}\alpha_{2b}] \\
&=
w(r_{12})[S_a,\alpha_{1b}\alpha_{2b}] \\
&=
w(r_{12})\Big([S_a,\alpha_{1b}]\alpha_{2b}+\alpha_{1b}[S_a,\alpha_{2b}]\Big) \\
&=
w(r_{12})i\epsilon_{abc}\Big(\alpha_{1c}\alpha_{2b}+\alpha_{1b}\alpha_{2c}\Big) \\
&=0 \ .
\end{aligned}
$$
The third term goes very similarly. Combining
$$
[L_a,x_{1b}-x_{2b}]=i\epsilon_{abc}(x_{1c}-x_{2c})
\ \ \rightarrow \ \ [J_a,x_{1b}-x_{2b}]=i\epsilon_{abc}(x_{1c}-x_{2c})
$$
with
$$
[S_a,\alpha_{ib}]=i\epsilon_{abc}\alpha_{ic}
\ \ \rightarrow \ \ [J_a,\alpha_{ib}]=i\epsilon_{abc}\alpha_{ic}
$$
leads to
$$
\begin{aligned}
\
[J_a,\boldsymbol{\alpha}_1\cdot\boldsymbol{r}_{12}]
&=
[J_a,\alpha_{1b}(x_{1b}-x_{2b})] \\
&=
[J_a,\alpha_{1b}](x_{1b}-x_{2b})+\alpha_{1b}[J_a,x_{1b}-x_{2b}] \\
&=
i\epsilon_{abc}\Big(\alpha_{1c}(x_{1b}-x_{2b})+\alpha_{1b}(x_{1c}-x_{2c})\Big) \\
&=0 \ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
and similarly $[J_a,\boldsymbol{\alpha}_2\cdot\boldsymbol{r}_{12}]=0$. Then
$$
\begin{aligned}
\
[J_a,(\boldsymbol{\alpha}_1\cdot\boldsymbol{r}_{12})(\boldsymbol{\alpha}_2\cdot\boldsymbol{r}_{12})]&=
[J_a,\boldsymbol{\alpha}_1\cdot\boldsymbol{r}_{12}]\boldsymbol{\alpha}_2\cdot\boldsymbol{r}_{12}+\boldsymbol{\alpha}_1\cdot\boldsymbol{r}_{12}[J_a,\boldsymbol{\alpha}_2\cdot\boldsymbol{r}_{12}] \\ &=0 \ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
and we are done.
Addendum
The above derivation establishes that the Hamiltonian
$$
H=h_1+h_2+W \ ,
$$
where
$$
h=\boldsymbol{\alpha}\cdot\boldsymbol{p}+\beta m-\frac{Z\alpha}{r} \ \ , \ \ 
W=\frac{\alpha}{r_{12}}I\otimes I-\frac{\alpha}{2r_{12}}\left[\boldsymbol{\alpha}_1\boldsymbol{\alpha}_2+\frac{(\boldsymbol{\alpha}_1\cdot\boldsymbol{r}_{12})(\boldsymbol{\alpha}_2\cdot\boldsymbol{r}_{12})}{r^2_{12}}\right] \ ,
$$
commutes with $\boldsymbol{J}$, and therefore the eigenvalues of $\boldsymbol{J}^2$ and $J_z$ are good quantum numbers. I just want to point out that this property holds even if a positive-energy projected Coulomb-Breit interaction is used instead of the "bare" one:
$$
{\cal{H}}=h_1+h_2+\Lambda_{++}W\Lambda_{++} \ .
$$
Here $\Lambda_{++}$ is a projection operator projecting onto the positive-positive energy subspace of $H_0=h_1+h_2$:
$$
\Lambda_{++}=\sum_{\substack{p \\ \varepsilon_p>0}}|\phi_p\rangle\langle\phi_p| \, \otimes \, \sum_{\substack{q \\ \varepsilon_q>0}}|\phi_q\rangle\langle\phi_q| \ ,
$$
and since the eigenfunctions of $h$ are also total angular momentum eigenfunctions, we have $[\boldsymbol{J},\Lambda_{++}]=\boldsymbol{0}$, and so $[\boldsymbol{J},\Lambda_{++}W\Lambda_{++}]=\boldsymbol{0}$ and $[\boldsymbol{J},{\cal{H}}]=\boldsymbol{0}$. The advantage of ${\cal{H}}$ over $H$ is that it does not suffer from the continuum dissolution problem caused by negative-energy states, and therefore can be treated variationally; also, it is actually ${\cal{H}}$ that rigorously follows from bound state QED, not $H$. It might be thus reassuring to know that the projection does not interfere with the symmetry properties of the Hamiltonian.
