Is the total angular momentum $J=L+S$ a good quantum number for the Breit intereaction?
I am reformulating this question because the previous one was closed to the to the claim that is a homework question.
According to Wikipedia the Breit operator is given by
$$
\hat{B}_{i j}=-\frac{1}{2 r_{i j}}\left[\vec{\alpha}(i) \cdot \vec{\alpha}(j)+\frac{\left(\vec{\alpha}(i) \cdot \mathbf{r}_{i j}\right)\left(\vec{\alpha}(j) \cdot \mathbf{r}_{i j}\right)}{r_{i j}^2}\right]
$$
Is the total angular momentum $J=L+S$ a good a quantum number in  2 electron system?

Possible duplicate by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/819948/2451

Hi amilton moreira. Please don't repost a closed question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit the original question within the original entry.

ok I understand
